# Functions With Easel JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, easeljs

I am trying (and failing) miserably with Easel JS and Canvas.  I'm a bit new to canvas in general and learning JS as well.  I am basically trying to make a canvas that I can update with colors, that are passed through a button click.

[I have made a Fiddle to show my work so far.](https://jsfiddle.net/8adsvgod/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>IllustratorSetup</title>
  <script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>      
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    var circle = new createjs.Shape();

    function drawRectangle(){
      var rect = new createjs.Shape();
      rect.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRect(10, 10, 80, 80);
      stage.addChild(rect);
      stage.update();
    }

    function drawShapes(){
      drawRectangle();
      stage.update();
    }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="drawShapes()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
    <button onclick="drawRectangle('#ff0000')">Click me for red</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your demo likely doesn't work because you are defining your stage before the body onload, and passing it the ID of your canvas (which uses a document.getElementById under the hood). The canvas element won't be available until it is created in the body.

I recommend moving your code that isn't in a function to an init(), or even put it into the `drawShapes` method.

```
var stage, circle; // Keep them global

function drawRectangle(){
  var rect = new createjs.Shape();
  rect.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRect(10, 10, 80, 80);
  stage.addChild(rect);
  //stage.update(); // Unnecessary, since it is called in drawShapes.
}

function drawShapes(){
  stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
  circle = new createjs.Shape();
  drawRectangle();
  stage.update();
}
```

You can also define your scripts in the body, after the canvas element, so that they initialize after the element is ready.

Note that your fiddle doesn't have the createjs libraries in it, and that JSFiddle will fire the code part of the fiddle during the onload event, so you may not see the issue you are having locally.